# What is it called when you increase the concrete floor (ramp it up) to avoid using a transition strip? What are the pros and cons of this approach?

Tags: floor

What is it called when you increase concrete floor by ramping it up, to avoid using a transition strip?

Comment: There's no specific term for it, and the pros and cons depend completely on what flooring situation we're talking about. Please revise to ask something more specific.

Comment: You can't "feather edge" ( taper it to zero)  concrete ; the thin edge will spall.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes **[sloping the concrete](https://www.concreteideas.com/fixing-poorly-sloped-concrete-floor-drainage/)** is necessary to drain water or create a ramp. The concrete is usually mixed with fiber to prevent cracking and to keep from using wire or rebar. You don't want to just add a small patch near a doorway to create a transition point, as it will probably crack.

[image]